# In Unity, what is the difference between the 2 ways to register a singleton instance?

Tags: c#, singleton, unity-container

In Unity, as I know I can use the following 2 options to register a singleton instance:

```
        IConfiguration globalConfig = new Configuration();
        container.RegisterInstance<IConfiguration>(globalConfig);

        container.RegisterType<IConfiguration, Configuration>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Is there any difference between these 2 ways? What is the preferred way to register a singleton instance?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first way registers an instance. You have to create the instance of the object when you do it.

The second way is not a singleton. It's a "singleton for any resolution by the container or any of it's child containers". The first time it would ever be resolve would "fix the state" of the object and register for any further resolutions, within the `LifetimeManager`.

For example, let's say you have the following class:

```
class AA
{
    public Datetime When { get; set; }
    public AA()
    {
        this.When = Datetime.Now;
    }
}
```

In the first case, `When` would be before the registration, in the second case it would be whenever you actually resolve for that type/interface.

Comment: It's a good example to explain the difference between the 2 options

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you register some **instance of type**. 
So, fields and properties of this instance were been modified until you registered him, because of this you can register some "state" of singleton. Hovewer, it's a very strange behaivor that you need register state of singleton.

In the second case you register a **type**, but not register some state of object. Of course, you can use specific attributes or injection params to set state of new instance.

**IUnityContainer.RegisterInstance** use **ContainerControlledLifetimeManager** by default if you do not specify other, see [Lifetime Managers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647854.aspx). Your two cases are identical. Hovewer, both cases do not register a singleton.
I mean you can register many different objects for IConfiguration:

```
IConfiguration globalConfig = new Configuration();
IConfiguration localConfig = new Configuration();

container.RegisterInstance<IConfiguration>("globalConfig", globalConfig);
container.RegisterInstance<IConfiguration>("localConfig", localConfig);

...
container.RegisterType<IConfiguration, Configuration>("localConfig", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IConfiguration, Configuration>("globalConfig", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

And you get not equals objects for mismatched registerName, but get equals objects for the same registerName:

```
// This objects does not equal in both cases
IConfiguration globalConfig = container.Resolve<IConfiguration>("globalConfig");
IConfiguration localConfig = container.Resolve<IConfiguration>("localConfig");

....

// This objects equals in both cases
IConfiguration globalConfig1 = container.Resolve<IConfiguration>("globalConfig");
IConfiguration globalConfig2 = container.Resolve<IConfiguration>("globalConfig");
```

I hope that its help you.